# facebook app style hide header bar when scrolling down, show again when scrolling up

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, jquery-animate

On the iphone app of facebook, when scrolling down the header bar shrinks and hides. When scrolling back up it is shown again.

I want to replicate this but also add in another div which follows suit.
I have created a simple fiddle to show what i have tried so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/0z6tqqyk/2/

However, when scrolling down on initial page load the actions work fine. But when scrolling back up there is a delay before the animation happens.

When scrolling back down AGAIN, there is a delay.
Any help achieving what I am aiming for?

```js
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $("#container").scroll(function(event) {
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        $("#header").animate({
          'marginTop': '-40px'
        }, 200);
        $("#title").animate({
          'marginTop': '0'
        }, 200);
      } else {
        $("#header").animate({
          'marginTop': '0'
        }, 200);
        $("#title").animate({
          'marginTop': '40px'
        }, 200);
      }
      lastScrollTop = st;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have animation adding and messing up the timing use the [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) API before adding a new animation.

After some testing: this configuration seems the most consistent:

```
   $("#header").stop(true, false).animate({ 'marginTop': '-40px'}, 100);
   $("#title").stop(true, false).animate({ 'marginTop': '0'}, 100);
```